# Device tree compiler throws error dtc: invalid option -- '@'

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am trying to compile an overlay and use it for study purpose but I am not able to compile an overlay.
For example I took an example device tree overlay from derek molloy blog

```
git clone git://github.com/derekmolloy/boneDeviceTree.git
```

and now I have a directory with a name overlay. In that a script **build** is there that have the compilation command for this overlay.
this is the command inside build

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Compiling the overlay from .dts to .dtbo"

dtc -O dtb -o DM-GPIO-Test-00A0.dtbo -b 0 -@ DM-GPIO-Test.dts
```

**DM-GPIO-Test.dts** file is the source overlay file and **DM-GPIO-Test-00A0.dtbo** is the output.

Now if I run this script I get this message

```
./build 
Compiling the overlay from .dts to .dtbo
dtc: invalid option -- '@'
Usage: dtc [options] <input file>

Options: -[qI:O:o:V:d:R:S:p:fb:i:H:sW:E:hv]
  -q, --quiet                
    Quiet: -q suppress warnings, -qq errors, -qqq all
  -I, --in-format <arg>      
    Input formats are:
        dts - device tree source text
        dtb - device tree blob
        fs  - /proc/device-tree style directory
  -o, --out <arg>            
    Output file
  -O, --out-format <arg>     
    Output formats are:
        dts - device tree source text
        dtb - device tree blob
        asm - assembler source
  -V, --out-version <arg>    
    Blob version to produce, defaults to %d (for dtb and asm output)
  -d, --out-dependency <arg> 
    Output dependency file
  -R, --reserve <arg>        
    tMake space for <number> reserve map entries (for dtb and asm output)
  -S, --space <arg>          
    Make the blob at least <bytes> long (extra space)
  -p, --pad <arg>            
    Add padding to the blob of <bytes> long (extra space)
  -b, --boot-cpu <arg>       
    Set the physical boot cpu
  -f, --force                
    Try to produce output even if the input tree has errors
  -i, --include <arg>        
    Add a path to search for include files
  -s, --sort                 
    Sort nodes and properties before outputting (useful for comparing trees)
  -H, --phandle <arg>        
    Valid phandle formats are:
        legacy - "linux,phandle" properties only
        epapr  - "phandle" properties only
        both   - Both "linux,phandle" and "phandle" properties
  -W, --warning <arg>        
    Enable/disable warnings (prefix with "no-")
  -E, --error <arg>          
    Enable/disable errors (prefix with "no-")
  -h, --help                 
    Print this help and exit
  -v, --version              
    Print version and exit

Error: unknown option
```

I did install device-tree-compiler before issuing this command.My system is ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit.
What is wrong here?

Comment: The overlay functionality wasn't added until dtc version 1.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct dtc for kernel 3.8 on ubuntu 14.04
Do this,

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/master/tools/dtc/dtc-3.8.x.sh
chmod +x dtc-3.8.x.sh
./dtc-3.8.x.sh
```

Now compile, this error should be gone.